# ng-container with *ngIf else template don't work with ContentChildren QueryList

Tags: angular, ng-container

I'm trying to dynamicly change content of component by `@ContentChildren` and  `QueryList` usign `ng-container *ngIf="condition; else tplRef"`, when `condition` is true `ng-container` content is visible by `QueryList` but when `condition` is false, `ng-template` content isn't visible.

My goal is to display different element based on condition which will be visible by `Query

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g2v6nd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep `<ng-template #ref>... </ng-template>` within `<app-container>`

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u6b5bd)**

```
<app-container>
    <app-container-item name="Item 1"></app-container-item>
    <app-container-item name="Item 2"></app-container-item>

    <!-- work fine if true -->
    <ng-container *ngIf="true; else ref">
        <app-container-item name="Item when true"></app-container-item>
    </ng-container>
    <!-- should display content from ref, but don't work :( -->
    <ng-container *ngIf="false; else ref">
        <app-container-item name="Item when true"></app-container-item>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-template #ref>
        <app-container-item name="Item when false"></app-container-item>
    </ng-template>

</app-container>
```

Comment: Thank you, works fine. But I don't know why placement of `ng-template` make difference.

Comment: Because `app-container` is a different component altogether, it will render the items only within it. Hope this helps. If you found the answer helpful, please upvote and accept the answer :)